# Adding with a button

Tags: javascript

I currently have a Javascript game where every hour in the game something else happens.

The game is set to start at 12am and I want to make it so that with the click of a button it adds an hour to the time.

My current is as follows

```
// time-related info 
var gameTime = 0;  // begin logging time, 12 a.m.
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "Time: " + "12 a.m."; // start the clock at midnight 
function updateTime() {
var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
gameTime++;
if (gameTime >= 24) {
    gameTime = 0;
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: 12 a.m."
} else if (gameTime === 12) {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + gameTime + " p.m.";
} else if (gameTime > 12) {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + (gameTime - 12) + " p.m.";
} else {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + gameTime + " a.m.";
}
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: How can I add a button that will take the time up 1 number

Comment: But what's the issue specifically? Creating the button (which would just be `<button>Add</button>` I guess)? How to bind an event handler? How to add two values in JavaScript? I'm sure you can find solutions to all of these on the internet already. E.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+bind+event+handler . Split your problem into smaller problems and find solutions for those.

Comment: Well, I know that  <button onclick="buttonClick()">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input> would be the html for the button. I am not sure how to implement the javascript to make the onclick increment

Comment: You already  seem to have the code to increment the clock. So all you want to know is how to call that function when clicking the button?

Comment: Found the duplicate via: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=javascript+call+function+on+button+click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// time-related info 
var gameTime = 0;  // begin logging time, 12 a.m.
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "Time: " + "12 a.m."; // start the clock at midnight 
function updateTime() {
var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
gameTime++;
if (gameTime >= 24) {
    gameTime = 0;
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: 12 a.m."
} else if (gameTime === 12) {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + gameTime + " p.m.";
} else if (gameTime > 12) {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + (gameTime - 12) + " p.m.";
} else {
    clock.innerHTML = "Time: " + gameTime + " a.m.";
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="updateTime()" >click here</button>
<span Id="clock"/>
```

Comment: Awesome, Seems like I was alreadt adding. I just needed to call the function onclick

Answer (score 1):

just add

```js
var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
clock.addEventListener('click', updateTime);
```

Comment: `clock.addEventListener('click', updateTime());` is incorrect. You need to pass a function to `clock.addEventListener`.

Comment: @FelixKling and where is `function updateTime()` not a function?

Comment: That's a function call

Comment: `updateTime` is a function, but you are passing the return value of `updateTime()` to `addEventListener`.

Comment: updated. @FelixKling, the things that pass by when you're not testing. haha. thanks

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo thanks as well